# Console logging in wildfly vs. Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, wildfly

We have a web-app which uses log4j2 as logging framework. in wildfly server each log entry which goes to the log4j2 console handler also appears in the wildfly server log. otherwise in tomcat the same log entries do not appear in tomcat internal log. 
how can we configure tomcat to write all log4j console output to its internal log file like wildfly does ?

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?